# Scipy's optimization incompatible with Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, multiprocessing

In trying to use Scipy's optimization algorithms to minimize a function that computes its value within a sub process, I discovered that gradient-based algorithms (basinhopping and L-BFGS-B so far) encounter the following error on line 562 of optimize.py:

> ```
> grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
> ```
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Here's a simple example of code that generates this error:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

def runEnvironment(x):
    return x**2

def func(x):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "x:",x
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)

        results=pool.apply(runEnvironment,(x,))
        pool.close()
        return results

x0=5    
ret=basinhopping(func, x0, niter=100, T=1.0, stepsize=0.1, minimizer_kwargs=None, take_step=None, accept_test=None, callback=None, interval=50, disp=False, niter_success=None)
```

Note that this code runs fine if the multiprocessing components are removed, or if a non-gradient-based algorithm (like COBYLA) is used.  Can anyone think of a reason this is happening?

Comment: Why does `func` have an `if __name__ == '__main__'` test?

Answer (score 1):

Your `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom is in the incorrect position - rearranging it this way works:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping

def runEnvironment(x):
    return x**2

def func(x):

    print "x:",x
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)

    results=pool.apply(runEnvironment,(x,))
    pool.close()
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x0=5
    ret=basinhopping(func, x0, niter=100, T=1.0, stepsize=0.1, minimizer_kwargs=None, take_step=None, accept_test=None, callback=None, interval=50, disp=False, niter_success=None)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Although I'm not sure I understand why this is the right location for the if __name__ == '__main__': statement.

Comment: @Peter: Since Windows has no `os.fork`, instead the `multiprocessing` module [starts a new python process and **imports** the calling module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows). If you don't protect the call to `basinhopping` with `if __name__ == '__main__'` then the subprocess calls `basinhopping` which will call `func`. Since there is an `if __name__ == '__main__'` inside `func`, this `func` call returns `None`, the default value when no `return` statement is reached....

Comment: @Peter: (cont'd) `basinhopping` is expecting `func` to return a numeric value, so a `TypeError`is raised when `func` returns `None`.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense.

Comment: @unutbu This also has strange behaviour with class methods, is this expected? My latest question explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291316/scipy-optimization-running-in-parallel-with-class-methods

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to create many little `mp.Pool`s each with only one worker
process.  It is also inefficient to create one Pool per call to `func`, since
`func` is called many times.

Instead, create *one* `Pool` at the outset of your program, and pass the pool to each call to `func`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    x0=5    
    ret = optimize.basinhopping(
        func, x0, niter=100, T=1.0, stepsize=0.1,
        minimizer_kwargs=dict(args=pool), 
        take_step=None, accept_test=None, callback=None,
        interval=50, disp=False, niter_success=None)
    pool.close()
    print(ret)
```

The `minimizer_kwargs=dict(args=pool)` tells `optimize.basinhopping` to pass `pool` as an additional argument to `func`.

---

You can also use

```
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)
```

to obtain logging statements which show in what process the functions are being called. For example,

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy import optimize
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)

def runEnvironment(x):
    logger.info('runEnvironment({}) called'.format(x))
    return x**2

def func(x, pool):
    logger.info('func({}) called'.format(x))
    results = pool.apply(runEnvironment,(x,))
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    x0=5    
    ret = optimize.basinhopping(
        func, x0, niter=100, T=1.0, stepsize=0.1,
        minimizer_kwargs=dict(args=pool), 
        take_step=None, accept_test=None, callback=None,
        interval=50, disp=False, niter_success=None)
    pool.close()
    print(ret)
```

prints

```
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/MainProcess] func([ 5.]) called
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] runEnvironment([ 5.]) called
[INFO/MainProcess] func([ 5.00000001]) called
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] runEnvironment([ 5.00000001]) called
[INFO/MainProcess] func([ 5.]) called
[INFO/PoolWorker-3] runEnvironment([ 5.]) called
[INFO/MainProcess] func([-5.]) called
[INFO/PoolWorker-4] runEnvironment([-5.]) called
```

This shows that `func` is always called by the main process, while
`runEnvironment` is run by worker processes.

Note that the calls to `func` happen sequentially. To get any benefit out of
`pool`, you'll have to exercise more processors with each call to `func`.

Comment: That's true, but I'm creating a pool with each function call so that I can release the memory immediately after the function is evaluated.  I'm working with some third party libraries that appear to have a memory leak problem, and this is quick and dirty work around =/

Comment: Ah, I see. That is a good reason for using `mp.Pool` inside `func`.